# Android Studio - XML Resource Error

Tags: android, xml

I have added an assets in the root or main directory using Right Click > New > Folder > Assets 
And then a sub-directory for the splash assets but when I add the asset via

```
android:src="@assets/splash_assest/RTBDevLogo.png"
```

I get an error that it's and Unknown resource type.  I'm spent some time looking for answers and everything I find is for the older version of AS and will not work with my version 1.1.0 (newest as of 4/21/15)

Do I need to import it?  Or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use assets like this. Try putting this image file in `res/drawable/` and refer as `android:src="@drawable/RTBDevLogo"`

Comment: What does one use the assets folder for then?

Comment: [Here it is](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules): "You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the `AssetManager`. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data."

So basically, you cannot use images from `assets` in XML as is, you need to read them in code first, which is probably not what you want. @baron159

Comment: Ahhhh Alright I have it working now but any Idea on how I can organize my drawables folder better? when I right click new directory it doesn't appear in AS

Comment: @baron159 if you are talking about `/drawable` internal structure then I'm afraid it's impossible to structure it, it should stay flat (no subfolders)(probably won't compile with subfolders or just ignore them)

Comment: @baron159 If the issue is resolved, do you mind accepting the answer? :) If you have any further questions, I will gladly answer them.